# iOS Firebase : Add data to firebase node of array type

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I got node in the firebase named "XXXXX". 
I want to add tokenids to this node.

But in iOS I am having problem updating tokensids.

Do we got functions in iOS for appending data to iOS Firebase?

or we have to first get the token from firebase , append our token and save the token array back to node ?

Any suggestion guys ?

Comment: To accept answer on stack overflow you need to tap green jackdaw btw:)

Comment: Accept one of the answers, please, to let other people know, that it helped, if it helped ofc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot append data to an array in Firebase using any Firebase query.

But, there is a way by using dictionary as  arrayObjectToAdd: true,

```
self.ref.child("ArrayMainNode").setValue(["arrayObjectToAdd": "true"])
```

To remove an array object, you can directly use

```
self.ref.child("ArrayMainNode").child("arrayObjectToAdd").removeValue()
```

Comment: "No, you cannot append data to an array in Firebase using any Firebase query." are you sure in it?

Comment: you can store an array , replace an entire array but not append an object to array in Firebase. I have tried and this is the best solution, one which even Firebase supports.

Comment: https://github.com/Pulichev/RideWorldIOs/blob/VladPulichev/RideWorld/Model/DataBase/PostModel.swift - 57 line. Function. Working. "/posts/" is array. I'm not trying to be rude btw:)

Comment: But we both are saying the same thing. We need to add the object to the array  as { object : true }. There isn't any Firebase method to append object to Array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "somePath/array").child(newArrayObjectKey)
ref.setValue("true") // or whatever
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by this way:

```
let refInsert = Database.database().reference()

self.refInsert.updateChildValues(["Your node": "\(new token)"])
```